# VBA 'Compile error: Method or data member not found' when bringing value into range

Tags: excel, vba

Complete VBA beginner and on a button click trying to take a value (it will be the eventual column value for pasting command) stored at RawData sheet in A1, convert it to text or a value (i guess?) and store it as `revValue` then add it to a range in a copy and paste command. I know the copy and paste is working fine when i just put Range values i.e. `Destination:=dir.Range("A30")`, but with `Destination:=dir.Cells(30, revValue)` getting 'Compile error: Method or data member not found'  ...sure it's a really obvious one but driving me nuts. Any help appreciated.

```
Private Sub Import_Click()

    Dim source As Worksheet
    Dim dir As Worksheet
    Dim revValue As Range

    Set source = Worksheets("RawData")
    Set dir = Worksheets("Register")

'Store the RawData Cell value as a text or integer?

    Set revValue = source.Cell(1, 1).Value

    Worksheets("RawData").Activate
    Worksheets("RawData").Columns("A:D").AutoFit

'These two function work fine

    source.Range("C1", Range("C1").End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=dir.Range("A30")

    source.Range("D1", Range("D1").End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=dir.Range("J30")

'This one doesn't

    source.Range("E1", Range("E1").End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=dir.Cells(30, revValue)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Cells` uses integers but you're using `revValue` which is a range variable.